# Find the value of $a^m+1/a^m+a^{2m}+1/a^{2m}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a+1/a+a^2+1/a^2+1=0$, and $m$ a poitive integer, then find the value of:

$a^m+1/a^m+a^{2m}+1/a^{2m}$

Only hints please..

Comment: can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

If $\displaystyle t = a + \frac{1}{a}$, then
$$t^2+t-1=0$$
First find t by solving the quadratic equation then find $a$ from $$\displaystyle t = a + \frac{1}{a}$$

Comment: that part i did already. I am stuck after that.

Comment: let $t_0$ be the root of the equation. Then $$a+\frac{1}{a}=t_0$$. Therefore $a^2-t_0 a+1=0$ solve this to find $a$ since you have $t_0$.

Comment: I mean I have the roots but how do I use it to derive the answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
\begin{align}
a^2+\frac{1}{a^2}+a+\frac{1}{a}+1&=a^2+2+\frac{1}{a^2}+a+\frac{1}{a}+1-2\\
&=\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^2+\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)-1\\
&=\left(a+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{5}{4}\\
&=\left(a+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\left(a+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)
\end{align}

Comment: I am unable to proceed after this.

Comment: $a$ is complex, and not nice value. It makes it very complicatedt to get my answer.